# SharePoint/Azure - Granting app permissions at tenant level

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365

I need to write a pretty simple program,, but this program needs to access our Azure/Office365/SharePoint environment to download (or otherwise parse the contents of) a spreadsheet saved in SharePoint/OneDrive.

So I'm following this doc here:
[microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)
I successfully create the client ID/key, but when it comes time to grant "tenant scoped xml permissions" (through https://company.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx) I cannot do it. I get "Sorry, only tenant administrators can add or give access to this app.".

This is the XML permission request/permission level i'm trying to assign to the app:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

So where and what permissions does my user need to have? I've been going through all of the different "admin roles" and checking all relevant ones trying to find the correct set of permissions to be able to do this.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem, this is my solution process, it works perfectly for me.

First, I created a new user in the tenant and granted him the **global administrator** role.

[image]

Next, setting up an app-only principal with tenant permissions.  `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`. (Please note that this is different from the URL you provided.)

[image]

Finally, grant permissions to the principal. `https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`.

[image]

[image]

By the way, make sure that your global administrator account is consistent with the tenant you are using.

Comment: Hi Carl, Thanks for the information. That is however the document I was following to get this setup. I add my client ID to find my principal, enter the XML permissions... then on the page "Do you want to trust ______ ?", it won't let me click the button to trust it... The page tells me that I need to be a tenant admin to enable the trust.  Even when I lower the permission level, same thing. I guess I'll have to keep digging to find what permissions I need to set for my user.

Comment: @boog  Do you have a `global administrator` role? I just did a test and it should work if you have a `global administrator` role.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvVX7.png

Comment: @boog  When I click the `trust it` button it reports no errors.

Comment: @boog  See how to grant users the global administrator role (that is, tenant administrator) in an Azure AD tenant.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal

Comment: Yes indeed, I am a global administrator. Not sure what the issue is, still not working for me.

Comment: @boog  This is very strange. I just created a new user in the portal, granted him the role of global administrator, and then went to sharepoint to create a new principal. When I clicked the trust it button, it still didn't report any errors.

Comment: Hi Carl, I still haven't figured out what I'm doing incorrectly on my end. I have every single "Administrator" type role added to my account. I'll probably try deleting everything and starting over. I appreciate the effort you've put into your response however, it looks live you've covered all of the bases... and that I must be missing something on my end. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I recently stumbled across this issue as well. It is possible that you are accessing the appinv page from `xyz.sharepoint.com` rather than `xyz-admin.sharepoint.com`. Accessing from the admin page has this UI and also solves this issue.

Answer (score 3):

It works when you add `-Admin` to the site URL.

The word `-admin` is missing in your URL; the URL should be the administration site.

The correct URL should be like this:

```
https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
```